# Transfer contacts from older iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, airdrop

I have an older iPhone. I updated the iOS as much as I could, but it only goes up to iOS 15.

With iOS 16, in the Contacts is a "Lists" link, which gives the option to AirDrop all the contacts to another iPhone. However I dont see this link on iOS 15. How can I transfer all the contacts from the iOS 15 iPhone to a new iPhone?

Comment: Not sure about closing as a duplicate as the OP is looking to restore **JUST** the contacts, not the whole phone. And if it is an old phone it could overwrite needed data. Me, I would use iMazing (or iExplore) and extract the contacts with those apps. While they are commercial apps they both (I believe...) allow you to use them for a trial period with no or few restrictions. And iMazing (at least) allows you to extract the contents of the contacts to your Mac or PC.

Comment: What is the authortative source for the contacts?  Surely it's not actually the phone.

Comment: @MarcWilson yeah it is actually the phone. no iCloud backup (yet) and no iTunes backup (yet). its a business setting, not personal

Comment: (shrug) Get one of the contacts backup utilities from the app store, run it, move the resulting VCF file to new phone, import VCF file.

Comment: @MarcWilson this task should be possible without third party tools. otherwise something is deeply wrong with the Apple ecosystem

Comment: It would never occur to me to allow Apple to be authoritative at all for something as important as my contacts list, let alone a single mobile device that could get munched at any opportunity.  You can state that it should be possible, and not get it done, or you can just get it done.